# jquery : how to show marker when panTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Google map location changing on when click on the button. Unfortunately **marker** doesn't show on the locations

is there any option to show **marker** while changing location ?

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();
    $("#panLA").click(function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#panLB").click(function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.70131647557699, -118.15599389648437);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });

    $("#london").click(function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.501417, -0.020886);;
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#leeds").click(function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.708214, -1.621459);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#cambridge").click(function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.231462, 0.147424);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#edinburg").click(function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.94756, -3.211026);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#miami").click(function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.77248, -80.186847);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
});

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5120, -0.12);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatlng,
//        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5120, -0.12),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        icon: "http://unfold.no/css/images/map-marker.png",
        map: map
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/D2W3j/16/

DEMO (with marker) : http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/D2W3j/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `var`-keyword from the marker-creation(to make `marker` global accessible ) and inside the click-callbacks call the `setPosition`-method of the marker:

```
marker.setPosition(laLatLng);
```

Here is a working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D2W3j/21/)

Comment: +1 To support your answer, I would like to present the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D2W3j/21/ I would like to add this to your answer, if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for creating the fiddle!